# Standard layout and non-copyable property

Tags: c++, c++11, noncopyable, standard-layout

C++11, §9/7:

> A *standard-layout class* is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions and no virtual base classes,
> - has the same access control for all non-static data members,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
> - has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.

So, is there a way to make a class with standard layout non-copyable? If yes, how?

Inheriting privately from boost::noncopyable will not work, because it made copy constructor private (hence not a standard layout). The boost::noncopyable's implementation is like this :

```
  class noncopyable
  {
   protected:
      noncopyable() {}
      ~noncopyable() {}
   private:  // emphasize the following members are private
      noncopyable( const noncopyable& );
      const noncopyable& operator=( const noncopyable& );
  };
```

Because of the private section, it is not a standard layout class. I am also note sure if private inheritance break any standard layout rule.

---

```
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <iostream>
const int N = 50;
struct A
{
    int data[N];
};
struct B : private boost::noncopyable
{
    int data[N];
};
struct C
{
    A data[10];
};
struct D : private boost::noncopyable
{
    B data[10];
};

int main() {
    std::cout<<sizeof(A)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<sizeof(B)<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<sizeof(C)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<sizeof(D)<<std::endl;
}
```

The output is :

```
200
200
2000
2004
```

The example above shows that inheriting privately from `boost::noncopyable` changes the class into NOT standard layout compliant.
I am not sure if this is a g++ bug (I am using g++ 4.6.1), or the standard is somehow violated.

Comment: Why do you thing that making the copy constructor private will make the class not be standard layout?

Comment: @Mankarse So, can standard layout classes have private copy constructor?

Comment: Functions are not "non-static data members". So assuming you've quoted the definition correctly, the "private section" doesn't make `noncopyable` non-standard layout.

Comment: I added an example where a class inheriting from boost::noncopyable including standard layout class (again inheriting from boost::noncopyable) is not a standard layout class. Can you explain this?

Comment: @VJovic : The size of the type increasing is orthogonal with being standard-layout (§9.2/20 specifically allows it) -- GCC just isn't applying the empty base optimization. If you want to check whether something is standard-layout, don't look at the size, use the type trait for it (`std::is_standard_layout<>`).

Comment: @ildjarn So, it works as intended. Thanks for the suggestion to use that template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a confusion here:

- the standard layout property is affected by attributes (and only attributes)
- the copyable property is affected by methods (their presence, absence and accessibility)

The two concepts are orthogonal.

**UPDATE:**

The following display the very same behavior that `boost::noncopyable`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {};

struct B : foo { int data; };

struct D : foo { B data; };

int main() {
  D d;
  std::cout << (char*)(&d.data) - (char*)(&d) << "\n";
}
```

The result is `4`.

I believe this is because of:

- has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.

Indeed, experiment shows that introducing a `int a;` in `D` prior to `data` does not increases its size. I think that the fact that `B` inherits from `foo` means that `data` (first non-static data member) is considered to be the same type as `foo` (base class of `D`).

This leads to an ambiguity: `foo* f = &d` would have the same address as `foo* g = &b.data;` if the compiler did not introduce this padding.

Comment: Ok, so inheriting privately from boost::noncopyable would also make it a standard layout class (assuming all member variables are public), since boost::noncopyable has no member data

Comment: I managed to create an example that creates a non-standard layout class. Would you extend your answer in such a way that it explains the behaviour in the example?

Comment: @VJovic: I think it is something to do with the fact that both `B` and `D` inherit from the same class. I can confirm that Clang 3.0 also introduces a 4 bits offset at the start of `D` at least. I am checking it out, but replacing `boost::noncopyable` by `foo` where `struct foo {};` produces the same effect.

Comment: @VJovic: I only have my thoughts to offer, which I summed up in my answer. It's definitely not authoritative, and may well be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do to make your class non copyable:

1. Make the copy constructor private.
2. Make the assignment operator private. (Where it gets assigned another type of the same kinds as the class itself).

You don't need to inherit from some boost class just to get that behavior.

And may I add, who cares about some fancy 'standard layout' idea. Program what you need and don't succumb to this extreme space theory.

Comment: Standard-layout isn't "extreme space theory". It's a relaxation of POD and it's (for example) the requirement for using `offsetof`. More generally it's what you want for structs used in `"extern C"` interfaces. If you need C interfaces, then you need standard-layout types.  If you find this stuff too "fancy" for you then that just means there are certain things that you could do with C++, but you choose not to learn to do.

Comment: Also inheriting from some boost class 1) is less typing, 2) catches *all* attempts to copy/assign at compile-time (otherwise the class itself and its friends can copy/assign it alright).

Comment: @visitor: with C++11 and `= delete`, `boost::noncopyable` does lose some of its appeal :)

Comment: "otherwise the class itself and its friends can copy/assign it alright" - not really, because the C++03 idiom if you're not using `boost::noncopyable` is to declare the copy ctor/assignment but not define them. So the class and its friends can't copy it either, it's just that you don't find out about the error until link time, whereas anyone who can't access private members finds out at compile-time.